# How to optimize an algorithm that returns the value of a positive integer x such that f(x) >=0 for a partially known function?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

The only things you know about this function are that

(i)  x >= 1 for f(x) such that f(x) >= 0.

(ii) It is strictly increasing when x > 0.

(iii) Evaluating the function at any point takes constant time.

How do you return the value of a positive integer x such that f(x) >=0 in < O(n) time, preferably in O(log(n)) time?

In O(n) time, you just have to keep querying the algorithm for all positive integers until it hits f(x) >= 0.

Comment: How do you do what?

Comment: Edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: What is condition (i) saying? That the first value of x for which the function is non-negative is positive? If so "f(x) >= 0 implies x >=1" is a more logically correct way of saying it. Or "x <= 0 implies f(x) < 0" is also ok.

Comment: That took me a while to word correctly, I suppose it makes it easier to understand if you put it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluate f(x) for x powers of 2, until you find f(2^n) < 0 and f(2^(n+1)) >= 0. Then bisect until you find the lowest value. It's O(log n) time to find the first power of 2 for which the function is non-negative, and then O(log n) to binary search in the range 2^n to 2^(n+1).

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, you can upvote and accept.

Comment: I can accept it in a few minutes. I will do that when I can. I can't yet upvote it. I'm a relatively new user, so I have to build up my reputation to be able to do that. I will when I do, no matter how long that takes.